# How to nest a network request inside a stream request for Twitter in Node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am using [npm twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) to create a simple Twitter Bot that reply's to tweets it's tagged in as part of a larger Node.js application.

To listen / stream tweets my app is mentioned in I wrote this code, which works fine:

```
client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: HANDLE}, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
        console.log(tweet.text);
    });

    stream.on('error', function(error) {
        throw error;
    });
});
```

To post a Tweet I use this code, and again everything works fine:

```
var message = "@"+tweet.user.screen_name+" Thanks for your tweet ";
client.post('statuses/update', {status: message},  function(error, tweet, response){
    if(error) throw error;
});
```

So my natural thinking was to post a tweet after this Twitter account it mentioned I would use this code:

```
client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: HANDLE}, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
        console.log(tweet.text);
        var message = "@"+tweet.user.screen_name+" Thanks for your tweet ";
        client.post('statuses/update', {status: message},  function(error, tweet, response){
            if(error) throw error;
        });
    });

    stream.on('error', function(error) {
        throw error;
    });
});
```

But this is where everything fails, the first error  block throws an error (and not a very descriptive one). So I guess this is because I can't call client.post inside client.stream.
So how can I achieve this the correct Node way?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Why not having 2 clients ? One to receive and one to post ?

Comment: Turns out I am even dumber than I thought. 
Thank you for your suggestion, works great.
Also for reference to anyone else, Twitter doesn't let you post similar tweets within a short timeframe, this was another cause of my problem.